# passing python arguments in different order along with its variable name

Tags: python, arguments, python-3.5

Im new to python and raised with a little task of creating a small script where a small criteria must be met. First of all, my original code works great. The only problem I need help with is how to set up the code in a way where arguments can be passed in any order with its respective value (before running the script). Now I have checked, and theres no post about that specific question so here I am.

Using python 3.5.1 for windows 7 x64

Here's the situation:

The script will require 4 variables (all floats). 
-var1, -var2, -var3, -var4

I want to run the script as follows:

```
>> python test.py -var1 4 -var2 5.4 -var3 7 -var4 3.2
```

But requirements says I must be able to run the script, where variables order dont matter as long as the value matches with the variable name on the left. Meaning...

```
>> python test.py -var3 7 -var1 4 -var4 4.2 -var2 5.4
```

Results should be the same running both scripts.

I cant post the original code Im working in, but here's an example of how I need to code to behave. No matter what order the arguments where passed when running the script.

```
>     x = var1+var2
>     y = var3+var4
>     z = (x+y)/var4
>     print (str(x)) #result should always be 9.4
>     print (str(y)) #result should always be 10.2
>     print (str(z)) #result should always be 6.125
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse
Also, values for var4 in your examples are different ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) module will handle this for you

> script.py --var4 2.3 --var2 1 --var1 11.234234 --var3 0

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--var1', action='store', type=float)
parser.add_argument('--var2', action='store', type=float)
parser.add_argument('--var3', action='store', type=float)
parser.add_argument('--var4', action='store', type=float)
args = parser.parse_args()

var1 = args.var1
var2 = args.var2
var3 = args.var3
var4 = args.var4

x = var1 + var2
y = var3 + var4
z = (x+y) / var4
print (str(x)) #result should always be 9.4
print (str(y)) #result should always be 10.2
print (str(z)) #result should always be 6.125
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a roll-your-own approach:

```
import sys

def main(var1, var2, var3, var4):
    # your code goes here
    print("var1 =", var1)
    print("var2 =", var2)
    print("var3 =", var3)
    print("var4 =", var4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    vars = {}
    for varname, value in zip(sys.argv[1::2], sys.argv[2::2]):
        vars[varname[1:]] = float(value)
    main(**vars)
```

run like

```
python args.py -var2 2 -var3 3 -var4 4 -var1 1
```

produces

```
var1 = 1.0
var2 = 2.0
var3 = 3.0
var4 = 4.0
```

Comment: thanks for your time! I highly appreciate it. It worked!